# slideToggle isn't working on an image input with alt as button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this `input`:

```
    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
    <input type="image" style="width:60px;height:60px" src="../images/molar_left_t.png" id="one" name="one" alt="button"/>

     <div id="div_one" class="collapse">3rd Molar: <?php echo $resTeeth['one'] ?></div>

<!--31 one more similar input images-->

</div>
```

And this is the final output of those images:

[image]

Now each of those images, are buttons, and I need to `slideToggle()` a `<div id="div_one"></div>` and `div_two` and until `div_thirty_one`.

I made this script using `jQuery` and tested it on one button only but it didn't worked, and no errors at the console:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $("#one").click(function()
  {
    $("#div_one").slideToggle();
  });
});
```

No slides when clicking on this image button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Changes made**

► Added a common class for `<img>`. With respect to that clicked img we can find the corresponding text and toggle it.

**Working Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $(".img").click(function()
  {
    $(this).next().slideToggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group col-md-12">
    <input class="img" type="image" style="width:60px;height:60px" src="../images/molar_left_t.png" id="one" name="one" alt="button"/>

     <div id="div_one" class="collapse">3rd Molar: <?php echo $resTeeth['one'] ?></div>

<!--31 one more similar input images-->

</div>
```

Comment: for some reason, your script works fine, and mine won't. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @androidnation Can you check the console? Did you add the class?

Comment: still no output at the console. But your `.img` didn't worked. You first answer was better.

Comment: did you add the class `img` to the HTML? `<input class="img" type="image" `

Comment: Yeah, now it works properly, but sir, how can I get all of the unclicked image into a new line, and only set the clickable image on a line alone ?

Comment: @androidnation It is a bit long. I prefer you post it as a new question `:)`